# Nestjs: No type definitions were found with the specified file name patterns: \"./**/*.graphql\"

Tags: graphql, nestjs

im trying to deploy Nestjs with Graphql backend server on Vercel, I am using schema first approach so there is a `schema.graphql` and `graphql.ts` in my src folder, you can see my code below, im following the nestjs docs to write my code, but it shows this error when deployed, can anyone help to fix it:

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: No type definitions were found with the specified file name patterns: \"./**/*.graphql\". Please make sure there is at least one file that matches the given patterns.","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"No type definitions were found with the specified file name patterns: \"./**/*.graphql\". Please make sure there is at least one file that matches the given patterns.","stack":["Error: No type definitions were found with the specified file name patterns: \"./**/*.graphql\".
```

`generate-typings.ts`:

```
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();

definitionsFactory.generate({
  typePaths: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
  watch: true,
});
```

imports for `app.module.ts`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      playground: false,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
    }),
```

Comment: How do you use `generate-typings.ts` file?